# Two instances of one socket.io connection

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

In our app, every time a user signs in a new connection in socket.io is created. So if a user signs in simultaneously on more devices, they behave as separate connections. Instead of creating a new connection every time, I'd like to check whether the user is already connected to socket.io and if he is, I'd like to connect him to already established connection. How can this be done?

Comment: It can't. There is no such thing as 'connect to an already established connection' in TCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the socket.io perspective, those ARE two connections. But if it was my app, I would do something like this:

- add a user identifier (userid, username, something you identify users by) to both the users' socket.io connection (so, each time you send a message to the client, you also pass this id)
- pass this id also to the client-side code on init.

So now the socket on the server side has its' socket.io id, but also your user id. Anyway, to proceed:

- send this user-id to the client in it's javascript files.
- on the client-side code, make a small adjustment to socket.io handler - for each received message (say, broadcast), you can now check if it's your current user-id and instead of saying 'User #351 says Hi' you can say 'You said *Hi* on another device' or something like that.

Of course, I'm not socket.io expert, there's could already exist a framework or lib addressing this.